ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'src' even configuring src as root folder by setup.py configuration
from setuptools import setup, find_packages

def get_requirements(file_name: str) -> list[str]:

    with open(file_name) as file:
        package_list = file.readlines()
        HYPENDOT = '-e .'
        packages = [package.strip().replace('\n', '')  for package in package_list if package.strip() != HYPENDOT]
       
    return packages

setup(
    name = 'flight_fare_prediction',
    version = '0.0.1',
    description = "A project for flight fare prediction",
    packages=find_packages(),
    install_requires = get_requirements(file_name='requirements.txt')
    
)


this is my setup.py after writing this, I execute a command 'pip install -r requirements.txt'
it will create a folder called project_name.egg-info and having some files, and the important file which is top_level.txt have a value 'src'.
Now this src act as root folder right, I have a two subdirs and one file named exception.py, if i want to import this exception.py in my subdir, I write a import statement like
from src.exception import CustomException
it raises ModuleNotFoundError, I have a clean folder structure and __init__.py on all dirs... it works sometime but it wont work sometime, what is the issue?
please guys help me to overcome the issue...

Welcome to Stack Overlfow.  Please review [ask] and provide an [mre] is possible.  At least show the actual project folder layout and the import statement that is throwing the ModuleNotFound exception.
